# Дженерик и интерфейсы

Tags: java, c#, наследование, generics, интерфейс

Как указать, что тип аргумента класса-дженерика должен имплементировать какой-то интерфейс?
Если можно, пример.
Вопрос и для C#, и для Java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C#:

```
class MyGenericClass<T> where T : InterfaceName
```

В Java вроде так:

```
class MyGenericClass<T extends InterfaceName>
```